# Present Perfect vs. Past Simple with unfinished time periods: this week

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

> I ____ (read) six books this week.

The correct answer is:

> I ***have read*** six books this week.

Why are we using *Present Perfect* since we specify when we did the activity? Is it wrong to say (*Past Simple*):

> I ***read*** six books this week.

Comment: i think ... here the sentence refers to completion of action in the recent past. hence the present perfect tense

Comment: It depends on the "national variety". In British English the Present Perfect Tense is the only correct answer. In American English both are correct.

Comment: @user307254 Really? Please provide a source for your claim.

Answer (score 4):

Present perfect is *the more likely* answer, but both choices are possible, depending on whether you view 'this week' as incomplete (>present perfect) or complete (>past simple), which in turn depends on when in the week you say this.

Comment: According to https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-use.html, the Present Perfect tense is used with *unfinished* time words, ie the period of time is still continuing. The answer in https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238696/unfinished-time-word-and-present-perfect confirms it, but it says that there must be also an expectation that the event will happen again until the end of the time interval. That is, the choice between Present Perfect and Simple Past has nothing to do with when the speaker says the sentence. It makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Present Perfect tense if something happened during an unfinished time period, such as "today," and there is a possibility it might happen again before the time period is over.

Baseball announcer:

- Smith has had two hits today. (The game is still on; he may bat again.)
- Smith had two hits today. (The game is over; he can't bat more before the day is over.)

Reporter talking about a hostage situation:

- One hostage has been killed today (the situation has not ended and more people can be killed before it is over).
- One hostage was killed today. (the situation has ended and more people cannot be killed in it)

Back to your question, I'd say "I have read six books this week" if there is the possibility that I might read more books before the week is over and "I read six books this week" if there is not.